# Komodo Edit Autocomplete to Include Adding Semicolons

Tags: autocomplete, komodo-edit

I just started using Komodo and I like it.  I have the Smart Editing settings set to do quite a lot, and when I type a parenthesis or curly brace, it adds the second one, which is great.  But in some cases I want to automatically get to the end of the line to add a semicolon without using the arrow keys or mouse. For example:

`echo ($var);`

So I type the echo and then '(' and Komodo adds the second ')' but then in order to add the semicolon, I need to right arrow to the end, and this seems clunky.

Is there a way to quickly add a semicolon after parentheses or curly braces in Komodo Edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up making a macro in JavaScript that adds a right command and a semicolon, and the hot key is `ctrl + ;` which is convenient...  This obviously doesn't cover all the bases, as one could imagine a macro that would go to end of line and then add semicolon.  I will see what I can do...